# Swift Can't append to String array

Tags: ios, swift

I have this array defined inside a class:

```
var pickOption: [String]?
```

inside my classes init, I am trying to append to the array:

```
override init!(reuseIdentifier identifier: String!) {
      self.pickOption?.append("aaa")
      print(self.pickOption)
}
```

but self.pickOption is returning nil, why? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to init it declare it like this

```
var pickOption = [String]()
```

as this line

```
self.pickOption?
```

with the optional won't run as in it's moment `pickOption` is nil

Answer (score 1):

With first statement `var pickOption: [String]?` you have just declared the array of type string but never allocate the memory. As this is optional type, it will be nil at the time of declaration.

You need to allocate memory for array before using it. You can declare array as this `var pickOption = [String]()` and rest of code will do the work!!